# button not working in MVC when JQuery SCRIPT tag is used in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

i am using script tag in my MVC view and my src for Script tag is "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js".
the issue iam facing is html buttons are not working/postingback.
If i remove script tag,everything works fine.
whts the actuals problem with my code.?

Comment: do you have some other script files added in the view?  when you remove the script tag do you get any errors? and please dont mind but its seems you are not familiar with jquery because you keep refereing the inclusion of jquery as the script tag...

Comment: `whts the actuals problem with my code` - you are asking what's the problem with your code and you are not showing us the code? You expect us to read your mind?

Answer (score 0):

there could be number of issues, the script tag you are refereing to includes the `jquery` library from the CDN. One possibility could be that there is some javascript code in the view that is disabling your buttons you can verify by doing the following

1)  keep the script tag (jQuery) included in the view

2)  in the script section of your view (if you have else create one like)

```
<script>
$(function(){
 $(":button").removeAttr("disabled");
});
</script>
```

3)  so your final code will look like

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(function(){
     $(":button").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
    </script>
```

check now if it works... if it works then it means that you have some code that is disabling the buttons and upon removal of jquery library js error would have occured that why it seems to work...